# Overriding colors in bootstrap via class versus manually modifying the several .css files

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My goal is to set nav-pills to a red color. Reading between these two pages

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/colors/#background-color
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/buttons/

my interpretation is that I should simply be able to add a predefined color in the `<div class "">`.

I want a red color and have tried the following:

- `.bg-danger`
- `red`
- `btn btn-danger`

When I change `nav-pills` to `btn btn-danger`, it *changes* but not desirable (form itself is rather ugly afterwards). So it's my guess is that the pills vertical code should not use the btn colorization methods. When I try to add the `.bg-danger` or `red`, neither one is displayed. And I'm attempting `red` even though it's not listed on the two pages listed above. Reason is because I see that it has a definition in the main bootstrap.css at the top.

```
:root {
lots of other colors;
--red: #dc3545;
lots of other colors;
}
```

So I've tried with `red`, `-red`, `--red`, `.bg-red` and `.bg--red` and all without success. As an FYI, I changed the color code to my desired red here (bootstrap's danger red hoping to keep my site consistent if I miss something).

How then do I truly override the color without editing the 4 css files or did I just happen upon liking one particular feature where customization isn't as supported as others?

Regular code with pills as default blue (assuming you have the bootstrap files of course).

```py
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code with the `.bg--red` modifier. Apologies, I have no clue how to highlight. I've tried with `<pre class="prettyprint">...</pre>` but it only messed up my code.

```py
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills .bg--red" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*edit1*
To clarify, the end result I'm looking for by editing the `<div class="">` is for the activated pill menu item to be red rather than the default blue. The results I've had by modifying  has at most changed the form background itself, not desirable and rather ugly; it has not changed the activated pill background. I'm not sure if that customization is available without editing the .css. As it is, the only way I can get the desired result is to edit the 4 .css files containing a reference to the pills color. I'm just hoping there is a way to do it at the higher level should I decide to have different menus with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to use `bg-danger` here. It is #dc3545 aka "red" by default. Also, there is no period before your class name when sticking on your HTML element.

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills bg-danger" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
```

Make sure you add it at the end of all other classes with background colors defined. The entire `nav-pill` section will be danger/red.

Comment: Yes, I copied the danger red over red in the bootstrap.css file. 

I’ll try the code without the ‘.’ When I return home. Thanks!

Comment: Removing the `.` allowed me to change the background of the form where the button exists but it doesn't change the activated pill background. I didn't clarify that in my OP so I added that edit. Is there a different method I need to follow in that situation?

Comment: Add it after `active` class name. It will be on the same element as the `nav-pill` class name.

Comment: If you mean like so, that doesn't make the change I'm looking for. It will color the background of the form where the pill is located to red but not the pill itself.

`<div class="col-3">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills bg-danger" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
 `

What I chose to do instead was update every reference in the multiple css files for the pill to the red color. It was the only way I could get it to work how I desired.

Comment: No, I mean `<a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>` but I very well might not completely understand what you want red. Updating the CSS is ok, just remember what you did for when you grab the latest bootstrap updates next time. Eventually, as you learn more about Bootstrap, you can learn to edit the SCSS file and update it that way.

Comment: This is an example of the css `.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #dc3545;
}`. The primary (unactivated) background of the pill is updated when adding to the `<a class>` and is definitely closer than where I started. But it doesn't modify this active status color which is what I'm hoping for.